# Something equivalent to Array.find() to work on object properties instead of array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Given an object like this:

```
const someObject = {
  ID_1: {
    // OTHER STUFF,
    index: 1
  },
  ID_2: {
    // OTHER STUFF,
    index: 2
  },
  ID_3: {
    // OTHER STUFF,
    index: 3
  },
  // ETC
}
```

I need to grab the inner object that has `index === 2`

If this was an array, I could use `Array.find`, for example.

```
const element = someArray.find((item) => item.index === 2);
```

What is the easier way of doing that to an object? Do I need to convert it to array before? Is it the best way to go?

Comment: `Object.values(someObj).find()` ?

Comment: @VLAZ that's it! I've completely forgotten about that. I'm always using `Object.keys()` but I almost never use `Object.values()`. Thank you, VLAZ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would get the entry

```js
const someObject = { ID_1: { "OTHER STUFF":"Other 1", index: 1 }, ID_2: { "OTHER STUFF":"Other 2", index: 2 }, ID_3: { "OTHER STUFF":"Other 3", index: 3 } };

console.log(
  Object.entries(someObject).find(([key,value]) => value.index===2); // note === needs an int here
)
```

Thes would get the inner entry

```js
const someObject = { ID_1: { "OTHER STUFF":"Other 1", index: 1 }, ID_2: { "OTHER STUFF":"Other 2", index: 2 }, ID_3: { "OTHER STUFF":"Other 3", index: 3 } };

console.log(
  Object.values(someObject).find(value => value.index===2)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the object and check if the object have the key `index` and if it has value `2` then return the object

```js
const someObject = {
  ID_1: {
    // OTHER STUFF,
    index: 1
  },
  ID_2: {
    // OTHER STUFF,
    index: 2
  },
  ID_3: {
    // OTHER STUFF,
    index: 3
  },
  // ETC
}


function recursive(obj) {
  for (let keys in obj) {
    if (typeof(obj[keys]) === 'object' && obj[keys].hasOwnProperty('index') && obj[keys].index === 2) {
      return obj[keys]
    }
  }

}
console.log(recursive(someObject))
```